# How to parse JAXLXml (XMPPStanza)?

Tags: php, push-notification, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the JAXL library to connect to google gcm ccs server. I am receiving the upstream messages sent by the application. I have a problem parsing the file. The receive message callback( 'on_normal_message' ) gives the XMPPStanza object to callback. I need to parse this object to get the actual message sent by the mobile app. The below is my XMPPStanza.

```
XMPPStanza Object
```

(
    [xml:XMPPStanza:private] => JAXLXml Object
        (
            [name] => message
            [ns] => jabber:client
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [to] => ID@gcm.googleapis.com
                    [from] => devices@gcm.googleapis.com
                    [type] => normal
                )

```
        [text] => 
        [childrens] => Array
            (
                [0] => JAXLXml Object
                    (
                        [name] => gcm
                        [ns] => google:mobile:data
                        [attrs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [text] => {
                        &quot;category&quot;:&quot;com.google.android.gcm.demo.app&quot;,&quot;

                        data&quot;:{&quot;my_message&quot;:&quot;Hello World&quot;,&quot;my_action&quot;:&quot;com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW&quot;},

                        &quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,

                        &quot;from&quot;:&quot;GCMID&quot;
                        }
                        [childrens] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [parent] => JAXLXml Object
```

*RECURSION*
                            [rover] => JAXLXml Object
 *RECURSION*
                        )

```
            )

        [parent] => 
        [rover] => JAXLXml Object
```

*RECURSION*
        )

)

The data that is required by me is in [childrens]. Its an array of JAXLXml objects. How do i get the [text] of this children. This is actually a json string. I am not able to json_decode this string because of the """. How do I get this data easily ? I have to create a ack message to send to the ccs server after receiving the messages. I need from, message_id fileds in the original message.

Thanks,
abbiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you extract the required text node (read http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2012/09/jaxlxml-strophe-style-xml-builder-working-with-jaxl-a-networking-library-in-php-part-2/ for how to), use html_entity_decode like this:

```
$ php -r 'echo html_entity_decode("{
                            &quot;category&quot;:&quot;com.google.android.gcm.demo.app&quot;,&quot;

                            data&quot;:{&quot;my_message&quot;:&quot;Hello World&quot;,&quot;my_action&quot;:&quot;com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW&quot;},

                            &quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,

                            &quot;from&quot;:&quot;GCMID&quot;
                            }");'
{
                            "category":"com.google.android.gcm.demo.app","

                            data":{"my_message":"Hello World","my_action":"com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW"},

                            "message_id":"2",

                            "from":"GCMID"
                            }
```

Comment: I still can't parse.can you please provide a small example to do the same.